# Method for MinimumBandwidthOrdering

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

MinimumBandwidthOrdering[m, Method -> "RCMD"]

What method is 'RCMD' in Mathematica?

Reverse Cuthill-McKee,
Reduced Canonical Matrix Diagram,
Restricted Minimum Column Degree,
other?

Comment: Take a look at documentation for [Graph Utilities Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/tutorial/GraphUtilities.html#267857294). RCM = reverse Cuthill–McKee.

Comment: I think this question is indeed justified, although I agree that the question could have pointed out _which_ `MinimumBandwidthOrdering` was meant. (There is one in the private context ``SparseArray``` and one in the ``GraphUtilities``` package. Nonetheless I upvoted and voted to reopen. @Domen maybe you want to post your comment as an answer?